# How to merge objects?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, merge, javascript-objects, extends

For instance, from these two objects :

```
var object1 = {
  "color": "yellow",
  "size": null,
  "age": 7,
  "weight": null
}

var object2 = {
  "color": "blue",
  "size": 51,
  "age": null
}
```

I want this (`object2` overrides `object1` except for `null` properties or properties he doesn't have):

```
{
  "color": "blue",
  "size": 51,
  "age": 7,
  "weight": null
}
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

**[Copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)**

```
var src = { name: 'Apple', price: 5};
var dst= angular.copy(src);
```

- deep copy

**[Extend](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend)**:

```
var mergedObject = angular.extend(dst, src1, src2, ...)
```

- shallow copy

**[Merge](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.merge)**:

```
var mergedObject = angular.merge(dst, src);
```

- since angular 1.4+
- deep (recursively) copy

If you want to not overwrite with null, you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28473889/angularjs-merge-two-objects-ignoring-null-and-missing-values).

---

**[Object.assign()](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/immutable/javascript-solutions/object_assign.html)**:

```
let movie2 = Object.assign({}, movie1, { episode: 8 });
```

- fot Angular 2+ (ECMAScript 6)

Sources:

- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function
- http://davidcai.github.io/blog/posts/copy-vs-extend-vs-merge/

Comment: Using angualr.extend will not produce the result requested. The object2.age null value will override object1.age value.

Comment: @SaeedD.true, but there is already a way to fix this. Check my link in update section.

Comment: Worth noting: angular extend and merge are way different. One is shallow other is deep.

Answer (score 18):

For newer versions (at least 1.4.0) of angular you can use [`angular.merge`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.merge)

> Unlike extend(), merge() recursively descends into object properties of source objects, performing a deep copy.

Answer (score 4):

Using angualr.extend will not produce the result requested. The object2.age null value will override object1.age value.

angular.extend(object1, object2) will produce the following result:

```
{
    "color" : "blue", 
    "size" : 51, 
    "age" : null,   <=== undesirable result
    "weight" : null
}
```

Use the following code to skip over null properties

```
for (var prop in object1) {
    if(object1.hasOwnProperty(prop) && object2.hasOwnProperty(prop) && object2[prop]!=null) {
        object1[prop] = object2[prop];
    }
}
```

This will produce the following requested result

```
{
    "color" : "blue", 
    "size" : 51, 
    "age" : 7, 
    "weight" : null
}
```

Comment: I found the discussion while googling the difference of `extend` and `merge`. In the case, we can use your code or call `angular.merge` if we have angular 1.4.x.