# How to merge 2 objects array to make it one object and json output using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have 2 object arrays and will use those value on checkbox for view. I want to merge 2 obj arrays to make it one json object file. help me please

```
 $scope.fruits = [
{ name: 'apple',    selected: true },
{ name: 'orange',   selected: false },
{ name: 'pear',     selected: true },
{ name: 'naartjie', selected: false }
];


$scope.color = [
    { name: 'red',    selected: true },
    { name: 'green',   selected: false },
    { name: 'orange',     selected: true },
    { name: 'yellow', selected: false }
];
```

And the view,

```
<label ng-repeat="fruit in fruits" class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" name="selectedFruits[]" value="{{fruitName}}" ng-model="fruit.selected"> {{fruit.name}}</label>
<label ng-repeat="color in colors" class="checkbox-inline">
<input type="checkbox" name="selectedColors[]" value="{{colorName}}" ng-model="color.selected"> {{color.name}}</label>
```

And the output i want like below:

```
[{
    "name": "apple",
     "color": "red",
    "selected": true
  },
{
"name": "orange",
 "color": "yellow",
"selected": true},
{
"name": "pear",
 "color": "green",
"selected": true}]
```

Comment: Those two particular arrays are mismatched when you look at your output. For example array1/object1 does match with array2/object1, but the next one array1/object2 seems to match with array2/object3 in your output. How are you supposed to know which colour matches with which fruit?

Comment: Some key should be there both objects.

Comment: @rrd thanks. What i want is like your example.
For example array1/object1 does match with array2/object1, but the next one array1/object2 seems to match with array2/object3 in your output. 
User must select Fruit first after that choose the color. No need to think about for matches or not. What i want is after user clicked i need to merge the arrays with json format.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `map` function for this.

```js
 var fruits = [
{ name: 'apple',    selected: true },
{ name: 'orange',   selected: false },
{ name: 'pear',     selected: true },
{ name: 'naartjie', selected: false }
];


var color = [
    { name: 'red',    selected: true },
    { name: 'green',   selected: false },
    { name: 'orange',     selected: true },
    { name: 'yellow', selected: false }
];

var arr = fruits.map((o,i)=>{
   o.color = color[i].name;
   return o;
});

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: i don't want to be map. I want merge based on user choose.

Comment: For example array1/object1 does match with array2/object1, but the next one array1/object2 seems to match with array2/object3 in your output. User must select Fruit first after that choose the color. No need to think about for matches or not. What i want is after user clicked i need to merge the arrays with json format.

Answer (score 0):

Use Angular merge [enter link description here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.merge)

```
var mergedObject = angular.extend(object1, object2);
```

And manual way by ignoring null and missing values would be

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28473889/angularjs-merge-two-objects-ignoring-null-and-missing-values)

Comment: NOP.For example array1/object1 does match with array2/object1, but the next one array1/object2 seems to match with array2/object3 in your output. User must select Fruit first after that choose the color. No need to think about for matches or not. What i want is after user clicked i need to merge the arrays with json format.