# How to merge two same object in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two objects in Angular JS with a same fields:

`notifications.fb 
notifications.tw`

How I can merge it and sorted by filed time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angularjs merge two objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28473574/angularjs-merge-two-objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [**`angular.extend`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend)

```
angular.extend({}, notifications.fb, notifications.tw);
```

**OR**

```
angular.extend(notifications.fb, notifications.tw);
```

Comment: Doesn't this override the properties of the destination with those from the source if the objects have the same properties?

Comment: @LordTribual no it will merge other..same prop will remains as is

Comment: Yes, you are right, if ojbect has same properties for eample time then will be rewrite, but it is not what I need, I need show all items from object. Thanks will try now and will response

Comment: @Faud as you asked in question about merging, destination obejct will be shown with the extra field which are not there in destination..basically source & destination get mixed

Comment: I dont think so, and I agree to @Faud. If those objects match completly the destination properties with those from the source.